# What pattern to use in this case (interface implementation)

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a dataset that can be created by a few ways, one of them is by parsing some text, the other way is from a CSV format, the third way is by importing it from a database.

Currently, this is the interface:

```
 public interface IMyDataMaker
 {
       public MyDataSet MakeData();
 }
```

and this is the text parser class:

```
 public class MyDataSetTextParser : IMyDataMaker
 {
       private readonly string textToParse;
       public MyDataSetTextParser(string text)
       {
            textToParse = text;
       }

       public MyDataSet MakeDate()
       {
            // parse the text and return the dataset
       }
 }
```

the csv parser is closer to the text parser, this is the database class:

```
 public class DbMyDataSetMaker : IMyDataMaker
 {
       private readonly SqlConnection connection;
       public DbMyDataSetMaker(SqlConnection sqlConn)
       {
            connection = sqlConn;
       }

       public MyDataSet MakeDate()
       {
            // connect to the db and make the dataset
       }
 }
```

Is this the correct pattern to use in this case?

Comment: Yeah, strategy will do fine in this case.

Comment: It is the right approach, but it's not the only one. Strategy is very handy when you need to change the behavior of application in runtime, however you can also use a delegate especially when your strategy has only one method.

`public static class MyDataMakerBehaviourFactory
    {
        public static Func<MyDataSet> Create(int criterion)
        {
            // Create a delegate according to criterion provided.
        }
    }`

Somewhere in code:
`var func = MyDataMakerBehaviourFactory.Create(criterion);
func.Invoke();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, that's absolutely the right way to do it. Use constructors to separate out the connection info for each subtype, and end up with a common 'read' method, just as you've done.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is really good. It's the classic [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) implementation.

You can now chose the real implementation by [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) or creation an method to receive one instance of the interface that you need.

Answer (score 1):

Just going by your description of your goal, this looks like the right approach. It's not any particular design pattern as much as much good object oriented design. There's an abstract base class/interface that describes how the data sources Can be interacted 38th in a clean way. The consuming class can use any `IMyDataMaker` given to it, without being concerned 28th the underlying implementation or data source. "Polymorphism" would be the right word for it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes your approach is correct as already mentioned by our fellow colleagues. However I would like to add something here.

You can use an abstract class to achieve the same.

```
public abstract class MyDataMaker
{
   public abstract MyDataSet MakeData();
}
```

Now you may inherit from this abstract class instead of the interface. This should also be a correct design. So the question arises which design to choose in which scenario?

1 If we use interface option, we allow any object from anywhere which implements the interface to come and join the party. You absolutely have no control over that inclusion. It's an universal approach.

2 If we use the abstract option, we will have some degree of control over the object which wants to join the party because we know from which source it originates. That is it must be inheriting from MyDataMaker. Besides you can do some internal, private or even public implementation of some bits and pieces if you wish to do so as abstract does allow this.

So which one is more appropriate when is highly subjective issue and requires thorough clarity on objectives.

And yes, If you plan to allow structure to join the party then abstract option is out because structure is not inheritable so interface is the only option.

Comment: And you can do both if you have some code that all or some implementations need to share. Use an interface for the client code, _i.e._ the one using it only needs a `IDataMaker`. Then you can create an abstract `DataMaker` that implements the protected methods everyone needs, like `CreateDataSet` and `AddColumn` from which `DbDataMaker` can derive. And you can also create a subclass of _that_ which is a `TextDataMaker` that handles text parsing which the text and CSV implementations can derive from. [1/2]

Comment: This gives you: one interface, a tree of abstract classes, and only one layer of concrete classes at the bottom. Of course, don't overdo this and create an abstract class for every interface where you don't need it. [2/2]

Comment: @CompuChip you are absolutely spot on with your comment. Don't overdo it is the key. That's what I emphasised it's highly subjective. I congratulate all who have answered here because once read all the answers and you have just started career in programming this session of answers can give you real headstart.

Comment: So much impressed I am that I am gonna upvote every answer here excluding mine!